# Limit of sequence (limit of Bilateral sequence)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a question related sequence and limits of sequence.

From definition we know that sequence is a function whose domain is natural number.Then we called a sequence (a_n) converges if for every ε>0 and every n>N(ε) implies that 
|a_n-a|<ε there exist a natural number N(ε). And it is denoted by (a_n)→a as n→ ∞ .

In lieu of these definitions we know that the sequence (a_n)=(1/n) converges to zero when n→∞.So this sequence is convergent. And (a_n)=(2^n) is not convergent any numbers since (2^n)→ ∞ as n→∞.

so far everything is fine. How about we change the definition of sequence a little bit and instead of taking natural numbers let us take integers as a domain. Then our sequence becomes: (...,a_-1,a_0,a_1,...)=(a_n) where n is integer.As far as I search on the internet this sequence is called bilateral sequence.

Then I tried find limits of sequence I defined earlier but this does not make sense. First of all I used traditional definition of limit of sequence even though I know that this definition is valid when we have a domain of natural number.Let n is integer(n not be 0) then

1st example:(a_n)=(1/n)=(...,1/-2,1/-1,1/1,1/2,...) it seems this sequence goes to infinity in both directions as opposed our usual sequence. Can I just say this sequence has limit 0. Since if we part (a_n)=(a_-n)'+(a_n)'(by + I do not mean addition I refer union operation in sets) then (a_n)'=(1,1/2,1/3,...)=(1/n) where n is natural number and (a_n)'→0 as n→∞. Similarly (a_-n)'=(-1,-1/2,-1,3,...)=(-1/n) where n is natural number and (a_-n)'→0 as -n→∞. (a_-n)'and (a_n)' both go to then their sum goes to zero as |n|→∞. So does this imply (a_n) has a limit of zero when n is integers?

2nd example:I took the sequence (b_n)=(2^n) where n is integer. By similar method above I got (b_n)=(b_n)'+(b_-n)'(by + I do not mean addition I refer union operation in sets). (b_n)'=(2,2^2,2^3,...)(2,4,8,...)=(2^n) where n is natural number and (b_n)'→∞ as n→∞. (b_-n)'=(2^-1,2^-2,2^-3,...)=(1/2,1/4,1/8,...) where n is natural numbers and (b_-n)'→0 as n→∞. Now in one direction limit of sequence goes to infinity in other direction limit of sequence goes to 0 but a sequence must have a unique limit so does this imply (b_n) is not convergent when n is integers?

Now as you can see at 1st example for (a_n)=(1/n) whether n is being natural number or integer does not change the result and we have a limit 0 for both cases. Similarly at 2nd example for (b_n)=(2^n) is not convergent whether n is natural number or integer.

I am not saying that this works every time or the method I used even valid here but how do we define convergence of sequence if we define a sequence (a_n) where n is integer. Or is totally senseless concept to think. I saw very few things about Bilateral Sequence it would be great if you suggest me any source book website etc...

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following.

We can naturally define convergence for a sequence indexed by elements of a arbitrary set $S$, using a notion of a *[filter](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics).html)*. So, let $\mathcal F$ be a fixed filter on the set $S$. A sequence $\{a_s:s\in S\}$ of real numbers is *convergent* to a number $a\in\Bbb R$, provided for each number $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a element $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $|a_s-a|<\varepsilon$ for each $s\in F$. For instance, from this definition we can obtain a usual definition by putting $S=\Bbb N$ and $\mathcal F$ a filter generated by a base $\{O_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $O_n= \{m\in\Bbb N:m\ge n\}$. Also we can obtain a definition for bilateral sequences by putting $S=\Bbb Z$ and $\mathcal F$ a filter generated by a base $\{O_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $O_n= \{m\in\Bbb Z:|m|\ge n\}$.

Comment: I will check filter and its relation with bilateral sequence and probably ask your help since the subject is new for me...I have one another question I believe that if (a_n) is a sequence and n is natural number and (a_n) is divergent then (a_n) must be divergent where n is now integer. even though I do not have proof yet this is clear to me...however could we say the same thing that is if (a_n) is convergent n is natural number can we say (a_n) is also convergent where n is integer. So far neither I could prove this nor I could find counter-example.

Comment: @leo Do you ask, if both usual sequences $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $\{a_{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ are convergent, is a bilateral sequence $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ convergent? The answer is negative. For instance, put $a_n=1$ if $n\ge 0$ and $a_n=-1$ if $n<0$.

Comment: good point. How about this (a_|n|) is convergent if for every ε>0 and for every |n|>N(ε) implies that |a_|n|-a|<ε there exists N(ε) in natural number. that is (a_|n|) converges if (a_n)→a as n→∞ and (a_(-n))→a when -n→∞. Does this definition make sense to you?

Comment: @leo It seems so: a bilateral sequence $\{a_n:n\in Z\}$ converges to $a$ iff for each number $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a number $N=N(\varepsilon)$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for each $n$ with $|n|>N$. That is a bilateral sequence $\{a_n:n\in Z\}$ converges to $a$ iff both usual sequences $\{a_n:n\in N\}$ and $\{a_{-n}:n\in N\}$ converge to $a$.

Comment: before asking my question i have to say that I am very appreciated your help thanks a lot...now I am trying to define bilateral cauchy sequence... a bilateral sequence {an:n∈Z} is a Cauchy sequence if for each number ε>0 there exists a number N=N(ε) such that |an−am|<ε for each n,m with |n|,|m|>N which is very similar definition of convergence. But in this time if both usual sequences {an:n∈N} and {a−n:n∈N} are Cauchy sequence, then bilateral sequence {an:n∈Z} Cauchy as well is a true statement as opposed to above for convergence case...do you confirm that or am i wrong?

Comment: @leo The [above  counterexample](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118199/limit-of-sequence-limit-of-bilateral-sequence/1120176#comment2290097_1120176) is not a bilateral Cauchy sequence, but both $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $\{a_{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ are Cauchy sequences.

Comment: is the counter example defined above not cauchy since it is not convergent or do you have other explanation? since I  could not see why the counter example contradicts with the definition of bilateral cauchy sequence?

Comment: The sequence $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is not Cauchy, because for each natural $N$ we have $|a_N-a_{-N}|=2$, despite that $N=|N|=|-N|$

Comment: thank you for all your answers... as a final question is there any book article note could you suggest me to learn more about sequence, bilateral sequence and convergence etc...